# Count number of times my code has been called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, count

I am trying to figure out how to code how many times my main program has been called.

I want to count how many times my program has been called, lets call the program "test". In the program different sub-functions can be called. therefore i want to be able to count those aswell, let's call them "program-1, Program-2 ...etc"

Also i want to be able to see how many times the program has been stopped, like how many times a user needed to push the kill-switch.

Anyone out there who might have any idea how to do this?

Comment: check out [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)

Comment: You could keep a log file somewhere with just a number that you would increment everytime your program starts

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable that will increment when the function calls or stops.

Comment: This won't help if we're talking about the main program being called and stopped

Answer (score 0):

The part of your question about sub-functions is called *profiling*.

Consider the following example that computes certain well-known function in a **very inefficient way**.

```
import cProfile

def fibonacci(n):
        if n > 1:
                return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
        else:
                return 1

cProfile.run('print("10th Fibonacci number is {}".format(fibonacci(10)))')
```

If you run this program you would receive the following output:

```
10th Fibonacci number is 89
         180 function calls (4 primitive calls) in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
    177/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fibonacci.py:3(fibonacci)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
```

The interesting part of the output is that the `fibonacci` function was called 177 times to compute the 10th Fibonacci number.

For completeness here is a more efficient implementation

```
import cProfile

def internal_fibonacci(n,data):
        if n < 2:
                return 1
        elif data[n]>0:
                return data[n]
        else:
                m = internal_fibonacci(n-1,data) + internal_fibonacci(n-2,data)
                data[n] = m
                return m

def fibonacci(n):
        if n > 2:
                values = [0]*(n+1)
                return internal_fibonacci(n,values)
        else:
                return 1


cProfile.run('print("10th Fibonacci number is {}".format(fibonacci(10)))')
```

That requires just 19 function calls

```
10th Fibonacci number is 89
         23 function calls (5 primitive calls) in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fibonacci1.py:13(fibonacci)
     19/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fibonacci1.py:3(internal_fibonacci)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
```

Comment: I don't think this fully answers the question. It doesn't tell you how many times the whole program has been launched so far.